# Binary search through IPv6 addresses?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipv6

A year back I had to implement a binary search through ranges of IPv4 addresses to work as an optimized HTTP request filter, to counter possible DOS attacks.

Today I need to re-implement this to work with IPv6, but due to so many differences in how to convert and compare addresses, this seems to be quite a challenge. I've tried to find an existing solution for this, but without much luck. At best, I can find simple IPv6 utilities to parse addresses and do very basic manipulation, without much provision for optimized searches. For example, this library: [whitequark/ipaddr.js](https://github.com/whitequark/ipaddr.js)

The key approach in my old solution was to rely on integer presentation of the addresses, using the following conversion:

```
function intFromIPv4(ip){
    var octets = ip.split(".");
     return octets[0] * 16777216 + octets[1] * 65536 + octets[2] * 256 + octets[3] * 1;
}
```

I then could merge/align IP ranges, so that a simple binary search was possible.

And here's the class I wrote to do just that:

```
function IPv4Checker() {

    this.ipList = [];

    // takes array of [{f,l}] integers and returns its merged-range version as [{first, last}];
    // works only if:
    // a) the array is ordered by 'f' in ascending order.
    // b) 'f' is always defined, while 'l' is either undefined or not less than 'f'.
    this.mergeRanges = function (data) {
        var ips = [];
        if (data.length > 0) {
            var start = data[0].f;
            var end = data[0].l || start;
            for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].f > end + 1) {
                    var d = {first: start};
                    if (end > start) {
                        d.last = end;
                    }
                    ips.push(d);
                    start = data[i].f;
                }
                var v = data[i].l || data[i].f;
                end = v > end ? v : end;
            }
            var d = {first: start};
            if (end > start) {
                d.last = end;
            }
            ips.push(d);
        }
        return ips;
    };

    // Calculates IP address against the current list,
    // using binary / logarithmic search algorithm.
    // It relies on the list of IP-s that is ordered by
    // 'first' in ascending order, and then with all the
    // range overlaps merged.
    this.isValid = function (ip) {
        if (ip === '127.0.0.1') {
            return true; // no checks for the local IP;
        }
        var addr = intFromIPv4(ip);
        var low = 0;
        var high = this.ipList.length - 1;
        var mid;
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = Math.round((low + high) / 2);
            var a = this.ipList[mid];
            if (addr > a.first) {
                if (a.last && addr <= a.last) {
                    return true;
                }
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                if (addr < a.first) {
                    high = mid - 1;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

What should be the right approach to creating an optimized IPv6 filter with support for ranges, to achieve similar fast search result?

In the end of the day, I just need an IPv6 filter that works fast with either 2-3 IPv6 ranges or 2000-3000 IPv6 ranges. That's because I need to use it on every HTTP request, so use of non-binary search isn't really an option.

And if someone can point me at a good existing solution that I may have missed, that would be awesome too.

**UPDATE**

Though I accepted the answer, the real help was the answer here: [IPv6 as a comparable JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329991/ipv6-as-a-comparable-javascript-string)

Comment: If ranges do not intersect - then you can store (index by) the first IP address of a range and search for "the the biggest address that is fewer than a given"

Comment: Aren't IPv6 addresses simply 128-bit numbers (as opposed to 32-bit numbers in IPv4)? Why can't you simply extend your IPv4 algorithm by using larger data types?

Comment: @cfh, do you think it is feasible to use 128-bit integers in JavaScript? Plus, even if it were, the way ranges are defined in IPv6 is quite different than for IPv4, I wouldn't even know how to do the conversion properly.

Comment: I re-published this question simplified: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329991/ipv6-as-a-comparable-javascript-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can represent any IPv6 address as a 128-bit number, your problem reduces to performing binary search on 128-bit numbers.

Now JS doesn't have the capability to deal with 128-bit numbers natively. So you could use a BigInteger JS library; a quick google search turns up [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer), for instance.

However, this is probably overkill for your application. You can simply represent the numbers as, say, a tuple of four 32-bit numbers. For the binary search algorithm, you only need to implement a function to compare two numbers written in this format. This can be done by a simple lexicographic comparison.

Comment: This doesn't consider the complexity of IPv6 address range presentation and how to convert correctly into the corresponding 128-bit integer. It's not as trivial as for IPv4.

Comment: @vitaly-t you can represent it as a quadruple of 4 32bit integers and compare them. The length of a number does not change anything.

Comment: @zerkms, I don't understand, what does it have to do with the IPv6 address range conversion?

Comment: @vitaly-t from the very beginning it's not obvious what is your **exact** problem. There should be no difference in implementing binary search through any kind of data, either 128bit or 32bit. There is literally no difference between searching through an array of 32bit or 128bit integers.

Comment: @zerkms, the difference is in how to convert IPv6 addresses with ranges to be suitable for the same kind of search logic.

Comment: @vitaly-t that's where you need to provide additional details. A range is either in a CIDR notation then you don't need math at all (but few bit operations) or it's a `(int, int)` tuple and then it's not obvious why its size matters.

Comment: @vitaly-t Parsing an IPv6 address isn't trivial. But parsing an IPv4 address isn't trivial either. Imagine how the old code would react to `192.0.513`.

Comment: @kasperd, this is not an issue here, na d it never is when you know to expect only valid IP addresses.

Comment: @vitaly-t: I don't see the problem with parsing IPv6 addresses. They are simply hexadecimal strings, with some separators which you can easily throw out, and some padding which you may need to do. There is nothing difficult here.

Comment: @vitaly-t `192.0.513` is a valid IPv4 address.

Comment: @zerkms, I'm not familiar with the different range presentation, but converting IPv6 into a comparable value is exactly the essence of my original question. Ultimately, I am doing it for storing addresses within a PostgreSQL database, but perhaps it's not relevant here.

Comment: @vitaly-t: Maybe you should post a new question on how to convert IPv6 addresses to numbers then? The question as asked doesn't seem to focus on that aspect too much and instead seems to be about binary search.

Comment: @kasperd, IPv4 spec defines each octet as an 8-bit value, so 256 is the maximum. Anyway, please, don't wander away from the subject here.

Comment: @cfh, a comparable value, to be exact, a string or number - don't matter. But yes, I was thinking the same here. Sometimes it takes to ask a broader question to understand how to narrow it down :)

Comment: @vitaly-t In IPv6 the maximum value of an octet is 255. But that doesn't make `2001:500:3::42` an invalid IPv6 address. Numbers larger than 255 can be written using multiple octets. Both IPv4 and IPv6 support a variety of different notations for addresses, if you want to support all valid formats it is quite some work to do so for either protocol. If you only need to parse addresses rendered by a specific piece of code which you know how works, then it is a lot simpler. But in either case it is better to use a standard library function than to roll your own.

Comment: I re-published this question simplified: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329991/ipv6-as-a-comparable-javascript-string