# IPv6 as a comparable JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, ipv6

### Preamble

In the age of IPv4 things were easy, because an IPv4 address could be converted into a simple 32-bit integer and then used for all kinds of comparative calculations.

With IPv6 it is a bit more awkward, because for one thing, 128-bit integers are not natively supported by JavaScript, and their conversion isn't straightforward at all. Which only leaves the option of dealing with a string presentation for IPv6.

### Question

How to convert an IPv6 address of any known format into a comparable string(s)?

### Requirements

1. For any comparable string, if address A precedes address B then condition `A < B` must produce `true` in JavaScript. Similar logic must be valid for the rest of comparisons: `===`, `<=`, `>` and `>=`.
2. For each IPv6 there must be generated as many strings as necessary to cover every range within the address, i.e. Start Address + End Address for every range.

Comment: won't string compare work the same way?

Comment: Post the JavaScript you've tried please.

Comment: @DLeh, it absolutely won't.

Comment: @j08691, I haven't tried any, I'm looking for an approach to converting IPv6 addresses to comparable strings.

Comment: if you haven't tried it, how do you know it won't work? `"2001:db8:1234:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000" < "2001:db8:1234:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001"` returns `true`, for example.

Comment: @DLeh, because you do not consider the range syntax in IPv6, plus the shorter forms for the address presentation.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by the "range syntax", can you elaborate better? provide specific examples of things you've tried, and why other solutions don't work.

Comment: For those of you confused as to why this is non-trivial, IPv6 addresses can be abbreviated in various ways to remove leading zeros and consecutive zeros (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Presentation). Any sort of comparison will have to include normalizing the addresses to a common format that either strips out all of the optional characters or includes all of the optional characters or which parses the addresses into numbers.

Comment: String compare should work the same way if they're canonical. For example, if we consider the filenames "2.txt" and "10.txt" they'd be compared wrong. But if we convert them to some sort of canonical form then "02.txt" and "10.txt" will compare correctly. We can apply the same logic to IPv6 address by converting all addresses to the canonical "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000". Then they'll string compare correctly.

Comment: @slebetman, see dgvid published a reply to this. And think of ranges defined like this `ff00::/8` then you'll see the complexity.

Comment: @vitaly-t: The canonicalization is actually not too complex. `::` can only apply once so count the number of characters and then replace `::` with the missing zeros. Canonical fields must be 4 characters so before doing the above pad any field with less than 4 characters with zeros. If you see a dot (.) then replace the dotted decimal group (must be 4 numbers just like IPv4) with hexadecimal. It's not exactly hard to do.

Comment: @slebetman, if you think this is so simple, why not publish an answer here?

Comment: I'm writing it but it takes a long time to type and people keep interrupting me :D

Comment: Since IPv6 uses 64-bit networks, you have over 18 quintillion addresses for each range. It is not possible to list every address in a 64-bit address range as a string. I use an array of 32-bit integers to represent an IPv6 address. I then do any address comparisons just like I do with 32-bit IPv4 addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin, nobody was talking here about converting individual addresses from ranges, only the ranges themselves: Start+End addresses. And you cannot do the same comparison as for IPv4 - see comments above.

Comment: Absolutely, you can do the same binary comparisons on IPv6 addresses that you do with IPv4 addresses. I do it all the time. I have even built an IP tool that engineers use for both IPv4 and IPv6. I simply convert the IPv6 address to an array of four 32-bit unsigned integers. It is slightly more complex than IPv4 since you must loop over the 4 integers, but the algorithm is exactly the same. I just don't see your problem.

Comment: @RonMaupin, IPv6 address range representation is the problem, for one thing, as was stated multiple times here already. If you have a range specification within your IPv6 address, you need to create multiple comparable values - Start+End couples.

Comment: I understand the first and last address of a range. I don't see why you can't do that. From a binary perspective, it is exactly the same algorithm as IPv4. You aren't seeing the forest for the trees.

Comment: @RonMaupin, and you assume that integer presentation of IPv6 for ranges fits into the standard non-range presentation to be used for range comparison. It doesn't.

Comment: In fact, in IPv6 the first and last addresses are even easier than IPv4 since the first IPv6 address is the subnet and the last address is the subnet plus the inverse mask.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I won't argue no more here. If you think it is that easy - please, publish an answer. I just don't see it being that easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conversion of simplified IPv6 address format to the full format is not too difficult. There are only 3 rules that allows addresses to be simplified. The following are the rules listed in the order they must be undone to convert the address back to the full format:

1. Dotted-quad notation (IPv4 address embedded inside IPv6 address)
2. Leading zeros may be omitted
3. Groups of zeros may be abbreviated with `::`

Technically, depending on how you do your processing, 2 and 3 may be swapped.

So here's a simple converter that only converts valid IPv6 addresses (it's guaranteed to fail miserably if you feed it invalid IPv6 address because I'm not doing any validation):

```
function full_IPv6 (ip_string) {
    // replace ipv4 address if any
    var ipv4 = ip_string.match(/(.*:)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$)/);
    if (ipv4) {
        var ip_string = ipv4[1];
        ipv4 = ipv4[2].match(/[0-9]+/g);
        for (var i = 0;i < 4;i ++) {
            var byte = parseInt(ipv4[i],10);
            ipv4[i] = ("0" + byte.toString(16)).substr(-2);
        }
        ip_string += ipv4[0] + ipv4[1] + ':' + ipv4[2] + ipv4[3];
    }

    // take care of leading and trailing ::
    ip_string = ip_string.replace(/^:|:$/g, '');

    var ipv6 = ip_string.split(':');

    for (var i = 0; i < ipv6.length; i ++) {
        var hex = ipv6[i];
        if (hex != "") {
            // normalize leading zeros
            ipv6[i] = ("0000" + hex).substr(-4);
        }
        else {
            // normalize grouped zeros ::
            hex = [];
            for (var j = ipv6.length; j <= 8; j ++) {
                hex.push('0000');
            }
            ipv6[i] = hex.join(':');
        }
    }

    return ipv6.join(':');
}
```

You can probably do the embedded IPv4 processing after the `.split(':')` but I've already written it with regexp in mind. As can be seen from the code above, each step of the process is fairly simple. The only thing that tripped me was an off-by-one error in the `j<=8` condition in the last for loop.

Comment: What do you mean by `simplified IPv6 address format`? And the same question as to the previous answer - how to deal with IPv6 address that represents a range?

Comment: "simplified address format" is the proper name for the shorter forms of IPv6 addresses such as "ff::1". The canonical/full address format must state all 8 hex groups and each hex group must have 4 characters such as "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000"

Comment: @vitaly-t: When you say range, do you mean subnet?

Comment: See the answer below - you get First Address + last Address for an IPv6 that contains a range.

Comment: @slebetman, the canonical address, as specified by RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952), is what you call the simplified address; it is not the fully expanded address. Your terminology seems backward. From the abstract: This document defines a canonical textual representation format.

Comment: You asked for IPv6 address of all known format. not IPv6 network address which is what you call "address that contains a range". We can solve that the same way we do for IPv4 (for example finding the start and end address of 192.168.10.0/24) -- apply a mask to the leading bits by the number of bits specified after the `/`. In this case, once you've got a canonical representation of the IPv6 number it's easy to split it into 4 groups of 32 bits then converting the hex string into a number then apply the mask then convert it back to a hex string.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Hmm.. perhaps I should have used "full address" instead. By "canonical" here I'm not referring to the spec but to the mathematical concept of a format that makes it easier to compare.

Comment: @RonMaupin: It appears that most documentation from comments in the Linux kernel to MSDN to BSD developer docs refer to the full address as the "canonical form". The thing you refer to as "the canonical form" is usually called the abbreviated or shortened forms. The RFC looks like it's using the word "canonical" to mean the "canonical form of the shortened address" rather than the "canonical address form".

Comment: @slebetman, I don't really know about that. It's just that all the network professionals with whom I interact use the canonical term to mean compliance with RFC 5952. For instance, I was asked to make my IP tool accept every possible IPv6 format, but to display the IPv6 addresses in the canonical form (meaning RFC 5952). My company has a directive that we use canonical IPv6 addresses (meaning RFC5952). This could get confusing, but, as a network professional, I feel confident in referring to the RFC.

Comment: Shouldn't the first regex have included a `:` like this `/(.*:)(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$)/`?

Comment: @kasperd: The `.` already takes care of it because it means the `:` character and all other characters. Also, since neither `\d` nor `\.` will ever match `:` it cannot be part of the second capture group

Comment: When I evaluate `"::ffff:192.0.2.1".match(/(.*)(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$)/)[2]`, I get `2.0.2.1` which is not the correct IP address. But `"::ffff:192.0.2.1".match(/(.*:)(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$)/)[2]` works.

Comment: @slebetman, I don't think the part for IPv4 works. If I pass it 127.0.0.1, I'm getting back `.0.1`. Anyway, what is it supposed to accomplish within the IPv6 conversion? Convert it into IPv6 - right?

Comment: @vitaly-t: It doesn't accept IPv4 address. It only accepts valid IPv6 address. You need to modify it if you expect it to handle invalid addresses. One example of a valid IPv6 address is: `2001::ffff:127.0.0.1` which contains the dotted quad notation (otherwise known as IPv4 address format) at the end of it. That is what it handles. Not IPv4 address.

Comment: @slebetman, is it correct though to expect string `2001:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:2700:0001` for address `2001::ffff:127.0.0.1`? Looks a little strange, the `127` = `2700` part.

Comment: @vitaly-t: You're right. It's supposed to be 0x7f. I forgot to `parseInt()`

Comment: @slebetman, thank you, it looks like it might do the job now :) It will take a more comprehensive test to know for sure though. Just so, since you tried to optimize the code, it is worth pointing out that `\d` is very different from `[0-9]` in a Unicode environment, and much slower ;)

Answer (score 3):

You don't indicate whether or not third-party libraries are acceptable for your solution, but if they are, I believe you could use the [ip-address library](https://github.com/beaugunderson/ip-address) and its dependency [jsbn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsbn) to parse each address as a v6 object, call `v6.bigInteger()` to get the address as a jsbn BigInteger object, then use `BigInteger.compareTo` to compare the addresses.

Comment: And how would it work for an IPv6 address that represents a range? - the very reason I listed requirement 2 in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that part. Does StartAddress in part 2 correspond to A in part 1 and EndAddress in part 2 to B in part 1? Or are they something else?

Comment: no, requirement one stipulates the values are to be comparable, and requirement 2 that values must cover all the ranges. A single IPv6 may need to be converted to more than one comparable value, if it contains ranges - couples of Start+End addresses.

Comment: @vitaly-t: You're confusing network address (ranges) with IP address. Does your IPv4 software also convert the address to two values if it contains ranges? Because ranges originated with IPv4. It's not new to IPv6.

Comment: @slebetman, when you need to search through IP addresses, those two things become semantics. If you have a range represented with just one IPv6 address, you wouldn't try converting it into Start+End IPv6 address instead, it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @vitaly-t: The difference is that software that expects an IP address such as a web browser usually never accept the range format (because it's a network address) and software that expects a range (network address) such as a router usually don't accept the single IP address format. My question is what software are you writing because what you're trying to do doesn't quite make sense. Which is why I asked: did you have this trouble in the old IPv4 world? Because this is not an IPv6 specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert an IPv6 address to four 32-bit unsigned integers and loop over the four integers. I do this all the time:

[image]

There are only two things you need for manipulating either IPv4 or IPv6 addresses: the address and the mask.  Both of these are the same length per protocol (IPv4=32 bits, IPv6=128 bits). Since I don't have 128-bit unsigned integers, I use an array of four 32-bit unsigned integers for both the IPv6 address and mask.  Everything else can be built from those two values.

IPv6 is even easier than IPv4 in finding the first and last addresses since, in IPv6, the first address is the subnet, and the last address is the subnet plus the inverse mask.

Comment: I'm looking for a JavaScript algorithm that would follow this logic: Check if the address contains a range, and if it does, get Start+End addresses, otherwise get just one address. It is a nice screenshot, but doesn't get me very far on the implementation. Plus, I find dealing with 4 numbers way more complicated than with just one string.

Comment: What I have been trying to explain to you is that the algorithm for manipulating IPv6 addresses is exactly the same as for IPv4 addresses if you do it as a binary number. For example, to get the subnet in IPv4 you AND the address with the mask. Do the same for IPv6, just AND each of the 4 address array elements with the corresponding mask array element. The exact same algorithm. I won't write your code for you, but I'm telling you how to do it. It works!

Comment: @vitaly-t: The check is simple: `address_string.match('/')`. The netmask algorithm is also well known: just AND the first x number of bits with 1

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ip6` npm package to normalize the IPv6 addresses and then compare them directly.

```
let ip6 = require('ip6')

console.log(ip6.normalize('2404:6800:4003:808::200e'));
// 2404:6800:4003:0808:0000:0000:0000:200e
```